# How to install YASM on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

I need YASM software in Windows 10 in Microsoft visual 2015 could any one tell the steps for installing yasm.
I already uses the below link.
https://github.com/yasm/yasm/tree/master/Mkfiles

with the help of source code I am not able to install yasm i got lots of errors in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I read somewhere that Windows users are advised to install yasm via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install)

First, you need to install chocolately and after that you just need to run the following command:

choco install yasm

So, You just need to run only two commands one for chocolately installation and another one for yasm. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the MSYS command prompt one can run the following command to install yasm:

```
     *pacman -S yasm*
```

yasm.exe is installed in C:\msys64\usr\bin

Comment: On a Windows 11 OS using MSYS2 UCRT64, this solved my problem. Thanks!